# Site Crashing and Restarting again

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, root

Hello i got a wordpress site http://www.flippish.com. I have some problems with my server coz it keeps on dying around 1-2 hours after i reboot apache then restarting by itself i think thats its because of apache settings i have it on MAxclients: 2000 ServerLimit : 2300. Im really not knowledgeable on this area 
my RAM is on 8GB how, the site is having too much load, do i have to upgrade ram for this site?

This is my top command

```
[root@hivelocity ~]# top
top - 13:57:34 up 6 days,  8:31,  1 user,  load average: 2.30, 1.92, 1.83
Tasks: 942 total,   3 running, 939 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us, 13.2%sy, 50.2%ni, 31.0%id,  4.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8051452k total,  7348388k used,   703064k free,   268420k buffers
Swap:  4300792k total,    71164k used,  4229628k free,  5876236k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1839 mysql     28   8 4435m 163m 4468 S 64.2  2.1 975:08.43 mysqld
23408 beta      24   4  288m  86m  10m R 15.5  1.1   0:00.47 php
   98 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.3  0.0   4:04.08 kswapd0
 9502 root      20   0 16072 2312  952 S  1.0  0.0  47:15.01 top
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   1:56.85 ksoftirqd/3
 1456 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   6:46.67 kondemand/0
 1458 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   2:26.01 kondemand/2
 1459 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   2:42.79 kondemand/3
 1461 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   2:55.99 kondemand/5
```

Comment: I'd investigate why mysql uses cpu : slow queries? Also why is there 5% of iowait? iotop will show you if it is caused by mysql

Comment: Are you doing any caching? If so, look into one of the many wordpress caching plugins, as they will likely reduce your load significantly.

Comment: Yes im using wp_super cache already. So its because of mysql? I have this for getting the queries 61 queries. 0.483 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your maxclients setting is quite high. If you actually had 2000 clients hitting your site, what would you expect the RAM usage to be? Would that push you into swap?

Try lowering your maxclients setting.